# Fetching data with android url

Tags: android, mysql

My android application works well when fetching data from MySQL using local host connection(IP address e.g `http://192.168.*.*:8080/file.php`). But when I try using a live shared host(can't use IP address because it's shared e.g `http://dav**ski.**izy.com/file.php`) with a host name no data is returned.

Answer (score 0):

try to use server ip, instead of `dav**ski.**izy.com`

Comment: Can't because the server IP is shared by other domains

Answer (score 0):

Sorry as I don't have enough reputation to just put this in the comment section. But anyway, the best way to debug the web to android connection is to run first the query directly on the browser from your mobile device in which your android app will be running.

- Echo the results from file.php in the web server.
- Run the `http://dav**ski.**izy.com/file.php` from the device browser with the query you would like to do to the web server ex.`http://dav**ski.**izy.com/file.php?id=1`, this query will be going to return all information with the `id` equals to `1`.

If the above returns a result from the browser but not in the android application, you may want to check your parsing logic or your android manifest.

Comment: I was hoping this wouldn't work but yes the browser did return results. So it seems could be error in my code but puzzling because it works perfectly with local host.

Comment: I'm using this example...https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrieve-data-from-mysql-database-in-android-using-volley/

Comment: this example with the local host also worked for me but when i change the URL to my live server(remember host name) I get no data

Comment: well, I guess your android code is not the culprit since as you said it's working on localhost, it's probably your live server having an issue. I have shared hosting servers and don't have any issues connection my android app with it. You should start debugging from the php codes if it really fetches some data in the database or not.